# Tabulator - Custom filter header implementation in React JS

Tags: reactjs, tabulator

I have a react app and have implemented Tabuator as data grid library.

But need to have multple custom filters like as image [attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wODk.png).

I can see that there is jquery example when I search multiple filters in documentation, but need in react js.

Do ReactTabulator component have any props for the above situation ?

I tried this: but it doenst work.

```
const Tabela = () => {

  const value = [
    {
      value: "name",
      label: "Nome"
    },
    {
      value: "age",
      label: "Idade"
    }
  ];
  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState(3);

  const fieldEl = useRef()
  const typeEl = useRef()
  const valueEl = useRef()

  const tableRef = useRef()
  const table = tableRef

  function customFilter(data) {
    return data.car && data.rating < 3;
  }
  
  const handleChange = e => {
    setSelectedValue(e.value);
    var filterVal = fieldEl.options[fieldEl.selectedIndex].value;
    var typeVal = typeEl.options[typeEl.selectedIndex].value;
    var filter = filterVal === "function" ? customFilter : filterVal;
    if (filterVal === "function") {
      typeEl.disabled = true;
      valueEl.disabled = true;
    } else {
      typeEl.disabled = false;
      valueEl.disabled = false;
    }
    if (filterVal) {
      table.setFilter(filter, typeVal, valueEl.value);
    }
  }
  function updateFilter() {
  }
  let ref = null;
  let columns = [
    {
      titleFormatter: function () { return '<i style="font-size: 20px" class="bi bi-card-text"></i>'; },
      field: "custom",
      hozAlign: "center",
      formatter: reactFormatter(
        <>
          <button className="edit" title="Editar" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#editarAcao">
            <img width="20" height="20" src={ImgSrc} alt="" />
          </button>
        </>
      ),
      headerSort: false
    },
    { title: "Nome", field: "name", width: 150 },
    { title: "Idade", field: "age", hozAlign: "left", formatter: "progress" },
    {
      title: "teste",
      field: "passed",
      hozAlign: "center",
      formatter: "tickCross"
    },
    { title: "teste", field: "color" },
    { title: "teste", field: "dob" }
  ];

  const options = {
    height: 200,
  };
  return (
      <main id="content" role="main" className="main">
        <div className="container">
          <div>
            <Select id="filter-field" ref={fieldEl} onChange={handleChange} placeholder="" value={value.find(obj => obj.value === selectedValue)}
              options={value} />
            <select id="filter-type" ref={typeEl} onChange={handleChange}>
              <option value="=">=</option>
              <option value="<">b</option>
              <option value="like">like</option>
            </select>
            <input id="filter-value" type="text" placeholder="value to filter" ref={valueEl} onKeyUp={handleChange} />
            <button id="filter-clear" onClick={function () {
              fieldEl.value = "";
              typeEl.value = "=";
              valueEl.value = "";
              table.clearFilter()
            }}>Clear Filter</button>
          </div>
          <ReactTabulator
            ref={tableRef}
            onRef={ref}
            columns={columns}
            data={data}
            options={options}
            data-custom-attr="test-custom-attribute"
            className="custom-css-class"
          />
        </div>
      </main>
  );
}
```